# Datatable show data according condition Sequence

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a data table with some records and have filter condition i.e

```
datatable.select("ColumnName like '090%' or ColumnName like '070%' or ColumnName like '080%'").
```

Now i wanted the datatable result like to arrange data like condition sequence means first records should be related to **'090%' then '070%' and '080%'**.

Can anyone help me for that?

Answer (score 1):

`Select()` returns an array of `DataRow`s. You should be able to use LINQ to sort them...

```
// using System.Linq;

var selectedRows = datatable.Select("ColumnName like '090%' or ColumnName like '080%' or ColumnName like '070%'");
var sortedSelectedRows = selectedRows.OrderByDescending(r => r["ColumnName"].ToString()).ToArray();
```

**--- update ---**

If you want to do this in a specific order that can't be sorted with OrderBy, I'm not sure if there's an easy way. Maybe try something like this...

```
// using System.Linq;

var group1 = datatable.Select("ColumnName like '090%');
var group2 = datatable.Select("ColumnName like '070%');
var group3 = datatable.Select("ColumnName like '080%');

var selectedRows = group1.Concat(group2).Concat(group3).ToArray();
```

I wouldn't do this if there are lots of rows in the original DataTable though. Performance would be pretty bad.

Comment: Thanks. But What About When datatable.Select("ColumnName like '090%' or ColumnName like '070%' or ColumnName like '080%'") Comes.. Please see i have update my Post

Comment: Thanks Anthony Chu. I have this logic already looking for best way to do this as i have millions of records and wanted to do in one query or one linq operation.